# GeoIP or browser language redirect on first visit

Tags: i18n-l10n

GeoIP or browser language redirect on first visit: how can I achieve this?

Comment: This question is too generic. You should report what requirements you need, or what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Well if you enter to the site, first time. Then you are redirected to a language that is set from administration panel, where you make relations between Drupal languages and browser or geoip. I can do the administration part on my own, but how would be the best way to do the language detection part.